# Angular8 - Getting File a Binary String from a Drop Zone File

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular8

In my Angular8 app, I have a drop zone where I can drag & drop files, such as PDF, MS Word, CSV, etc. I am using the technique found on this [blog](https://medium.com/@tarekabdelkhalek/how-to-create-a-drag-and-drop-file-uploading-in-angular-78d9eba0b854), but also documented by [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#selecting_files_using_drag_and_drop). The code works very well, but the one important thing I can't figure out is how to capture the file bytes being uploaded, so that I can save them to the database.

I placed a screenshot of the Opera browser source debugger below, showing the typescript and resulting `fileObj` and `blobObj` values. The debugger complains about `readAsBinaryString(blobObj)`, saying that `blobObj` is not a `Blob`. Looking at the `blobObj` value, I can see it's not a Blob that I've seen before. And, looking at all the values, none stand-out to me as a Blob. Also, the file bytes aren't obvious either. Looking at the `html`, below, I can't think of a change that would reveal the bytes.

I'm hoping someone with drag and drop experience can explain how it's done.

Thanks!

**Debugger Screenshot**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-forum">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="container" style="float: left; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" appDnd (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)" (itemDropped)="onItemDropped($event)">
          <input type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)" />
          <img src="assets/img/dnd/ic-upload-file.svg" alt="">
          <h3>Drag and drop file here</h3>
          <h3>or</h3>              
          <label for="fileDropRef" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; height: 25px; padding: 5px 5px;">Browse for File</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="files-list" style="width: 35%;">
          <div class="single-file" *ngFor="let file of files; let i = index">
            <img src="assets/img/dnd/ic-file.svg" width="45px" alt="file">
            <div class="info">
              <h4 class="name">
                {{ file?.name }}
              </h4>
              <p class="size">
                {{ formatBytes(file) }}
              </p>
              <app-progress [progress]="file?.progress" style="width: 200px;"></app-progress>
            </div>
            <img src="assets/img/dnd/ic-delete-file.svg" class="delete" width="20px" alt="file" (click)="deleteFile(i)">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const reader = new FileReader();

// FileReader has an onload event that you handle when it has loaded data
reader.onload = (e: any) => {
  const data = e.target.result as any;
  console.log({type: 'GalleryComponent prepareFilesList - data:', data});
};

// this will kick off the onload handler above
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```